# PDO_ODBC: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I'm trying to access an ODBC connection in PHP via PDO_ODBC. This is my code:

`$db = new PDO('odbc:MyDSN', '', '');`

And I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default driver specified

I know the DSN is working because I can use it in Python with pyodbc. The type is User DSN - does it need to be a System DSN? I'm not specifying a driver because I figured ODBC was abstracting that away, but maybe I need to? The underlying DB is Oracle, if that helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two separate Microsoft ODBC Administrator apps, one for 32-bit and one for 64.

As [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976) KB article explains:

> The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the
>   %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder.
>
> The 64-bit version of the
>   Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32
>   folder.

Nope, not a typo -- the 32-bit version is in the `SysWoW64` folder and the 64-bit is in the `System32` folder. (o_O)

I was running a 64-bit web server which was checking the 64-bit ODBC library for the DSN, whereas I had it in the 32-bit. Downgrading the server did the trick.